# Tkinter title bar doesnt change

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
win=tk.Tk()
win.title=('python')
win.resizable(True,True)
tk.Label(win, text='why').grid(column=0,row=0)

def button():
    tk.Text
win.mainloop()
```

What I got: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KrqU.png)

What I expected: The title bar is "python" and not "tk"

I am unsure what I did wrong here

Comment: It is only ```win.title('python')```

Answer (score 0):

You put an extra `=` sign `win.title=('python')`

It is simply

```
win.title('python')
```